# JBoss Developer Studio 9.1.0 FUSE CXF project always give maven error

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cxf, jboss-developer-studio

I'm new to JBosse Fuse and I have gone through Fuse examples which related to cxf ([quick start projects](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts/tree/master/cxf))and when I try to import those sample projects in to  work space I'm always getting this kind of error mesage.

**Failure to find org.jboss.quickstarts.fuse:cxf:pom:6.3.0.redhat-187 in https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga was cached in the local repository , resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of redhat-ga-repository has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM.**

[image]

Can please some one explain how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked with sample code(Quick start) and I was able to clean and build it after removing the **parent tags** as show in below.

[image]

So just you need to comment or remove that section from pom.xml file.

Comment: Ohh I didn't try to remove this section before I raised the question. It works Thanks :)